# update_attributes on association with ajax does insert instead of update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use ajax to manage presentations into a `Subscription` model. Each subscription can have many presentations. The presentations form lives as a separate form within the subscription form and uses `remote=true` to perform the update.

When I do: `insert, reload page, insert` nothing goes wrong. However, when I do: `insert, insert` it will end up with three different records instead of two with one record being updated.

The code that is called by javascript is:

```
def update_properties
  Subscription.skip_callback(:save, :after, :notify_observer)

  if !subscription_params[:presentations_attributes].nil?
    returns = @subscription.update_attributes(presentations_attributes: subscription_params[:presentations_attributes])
  end

  if returns
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

`@subscription` is taken from the method:

```
def set_subscription
  @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
end
```

The `subscription_params` method:

```
def subscription_params
  params.require(:subscription).permit(:role, presentations_attributes: [:id, :title, :presentation_id, :_destroy, :subscription_id])
end
```

Comment: Not really sure to understand but this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9944065/5006469) may help you.